# I'm getting MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.null'

Tags: java, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm getting this error and I don't why I tried the statement on workbench and it worked.
I'm looking also to improve my dates subtracting code basically I'm getting deadline from the table and I'm subtracting from today's date.

```
public boolean checkLessThanWeek(User userWhoWantsToExtendDeadline,BorrowedBook book) throws ParseException {
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Deadline FROM library_students.borrowedcopies WHERE LenderToID =" + "'" + userWhoWantsToExtendDeadline.getId()+ "'"+"And Barcode="+"."+book.getbookID());
        if (rs.next()) {             
            SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date deadline = format.parse(rs.getString(1));
            Date date=new Date();
            String today=format.format(date.getDate());
            date = format.parse(today);
            long milliseconds=date.getTime()-deadline.getTime();
            long days = milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            System.out.print(days);

        }
        rs.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a space in `"'"+"And `, i.e. `"'"+" And `.  And `Barcode="+"."+book.getbookID()` doesn't look right; should it be surrounded in apostrophes?  Also, book.getbookID() is returning null.

Comment: In depends if book.getbookID() return String then yes it must be surrounded in apostrophes. If return number then no.

Comment: @Pulszar since it returns null, I'm assuming it's probably returning a String.

Comment: You should add the error message to the original post. And you should your parameter binding instead of manual concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because `book.getbookID()` returns null and because you for some reason have a dot (`.`) before it in your Sql. Besides this it is preferred to have a parameterized Sql statement using `?` and also basic error handling is a good thing.

```
if (userWhoWantsToExtendDeadline == null || book == null || book.getbookID() == null {
    //throw exception perhaps or log?
    return false;
}

String query = "SELECT Deadline FROM library_students.borrowedcopies WHERE LenderToID = ? AND Barcode = ?";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(query);

stmt.setInt(1, userWhoWantsToExtendDeadline.getId());
stmt.setString(2, book.getbookID());
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Note that I assumed your first parameter is an `int` and the second one is a `String` but of course ths might need to be changed

Comment: Yeah getBookID() was returning null I had mistake in the controller Thanks